# Проблема с решением задачи "Шахматная доска"

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы

Текст задачи:

Даны два числа `n` и `m`. Создайте двумерный массив размером `n×m` и заполните его символами `1` и `0` в шахматном порядке. В левом верхнем углу должна стоять единица.

Данную задачу необходимо решить с помощью генератора, который заполнит матрицу `A`. Вы должны отправить на проверку единственную строку вида:

```py
A = [текст генератора]
```

Например:

```
3 4
```

```
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
```

Код:

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())

# Сюда надо вставить генератор

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        print(A[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
```

Что я сделал::

```
A = [['10'[(j + 1) % 2] for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

Но выводит `0 1 0 1, 0 1 0 1, 0 1 0 1`. Не могу понять в чём ошибка

Comment: @Сергей Я на форуме недавно. чем тут оплачивать? Баллы какие-то есть?

Comment: Это в некотором роде шутка была грустная. Сам текст запроса выглядит так, будто тут какая-то биржа по выполнению домашних заданий. Не хватает только добавить после "срочно" слова типа "слуги мои"... ("Официант, водки, срочно!")

Comment: Это был сарказм. До вас хотели донести, что здесь сильно не любят вопросы типа "Срочно решите за меня задачу". На Stack Overflow мы помогаем с решением, но не решаем задачу за вас, ещё и срочно

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы он был сосредоточен на сложности в решении, а не на том, что вам срочно что-то нужно. Возможно, тогда вам помогут

Comment: @nomnoms12 Извините за формулировку)) Просто задание нужно сдать до конца дня (

Comment: Вообще по-хорошему, как уже написали выше, стоит акцентировать своё внимание на самом вопросе и попытках решения минимально воспроизводимого кода, а не на срочности — иначе могут и закрыть как учебное задание без попыток решения/решить на халяву и т.д.

Comment: @Artom Вы не исправимы :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В своём решении вы учитываете чередование в строке, но не учитываете чередование самих строк. За номер строки в вашем коде отвечает переменная `i`.

Вы можете использовать тот же подход, что и со столбцами:

- `i % 2 == 0` — строка чётная
- `i % 2 == 1` — строка нечётная

Сложите индекс столбца с индексом строки и только потом возьмите остаток от деления. Тогда ваше решение будет верным:

```py
A = [['10'[(j + i) % 2] for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

---

Но его ещё можно упростить. Нет нужды в использовании строки:

```py
A = [[(j + i + 1) % 2 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Ой, точно. Спасибо большое! И за замечания к моему вопросу тоже)

Comment: ...и в итоге мы всё равно получаем неверный результат, так как Ваш код ставит в левый верхний угол **нуль**, хотя требуется **единица**.

Comment: @4500zenja Исправил неточность, добавив 1 перед взятием остатка

Comment: @nomnoms12 спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написали выше, лучше не стоит так налегать на "срочность" задания, нежели на сам код, который был представлен вместе с задачей. В противном же случае будут считать, что они должны срочно что-то сделать за Вас. На будущее могу предложить ознакомиться с FAQ по [хорошему написанию вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Если же говорить про сам код, то Вы просто вставили в выражение `(j + 1)` единицу вместо `1`, из-за чего параметр `i` просто пропадает, в отличие от `j`.

```py
n, m = map(int, input().split())

A = [['10'[(j + i) % 2] for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        print(A[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
# 1 0 1 0 
# 0 1 0 1 
# 1 0 1 0
```

UPD: если хочется покрасивее и без строки, то можно написать так:

```py
A = [[(j + i + 1) % 2 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```